# IndexError: list index out of range How can i solve this and make it run?

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdZnN.png)

I am getting the IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please see [help] and [ask] to learn how to craft an on-topic question.Please *do not* post images of code. Post code as *formatted text in the question itself*. You can copy-and-paste directly from the editor, and then highlight and press ctrl-k for code-formatting

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should know is, `randint(start, end)` function randomly generates number starting from the `start`  to `end`. So in your case, it generates a number more than what indexes you have in your lists. You can do,

```
people = randint(0, len(persons)-1)
```

Comment: Thank you!!!  I was wondering if you could also help with the yes or no part too. I'm supposed to make it so that if they say yes the whole program starts over and when they say no it ends the program.

Comment: you can use `input()` function to take input from user in the terminal. If you found the answer helpful then please upvote it and mark it as the best answer. Thank you !

Comment: can you show me how to do it please

Comment: I suggest you to ask a new question for this.